# "Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND" error when making an HTTPs request

Tags: javascript, https, aws-lambda

here's the code in AWS Lambda function:

```
var https = require('https');
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var params = {
        host: "bittrex.com",
        path: "/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries"
    };
    var req = https.request(params, function(res) {
        var test = res.toString();
        console.log(JSON.parse(test));
        //console.log(JSON.parse(res.toString()));
    });
    req.end();
};
```

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://bittrex.com
> https://bittrex.com:443
> at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
> at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)

Other solutions did not work.

Comment: @MarkB, what is VPC?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I modified your code to work correctly in AWS Lambda Node.js 6.10. I set the Lambda timeout to be 60 seconds for testing.

The big change is adding "res.on('data', function(chunk) {}:" and "res.on('end', function() {}".

```
var https = require('https');
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var params = {
        host: "bittrex.com",
        path: "/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries"
    };
    var req = https.request(params, function(res) {
        let data = '';
        console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            console.log("DONE");
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        });
    });
    req.end();
};
```

Answer (score 23):

Remove the `https://` from the host.  The require already says you're using https/SSL.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is with your security groups. Looks like your lambda doesn’t have access to resolve DNS. Check if you lambda sec groups have port 53 UDP and TCP enabled.

Comment: Lambda by default has no security group. It only has one if you change it's network configuration to run inside your VPC

Comment: Yes by default it doesn’t have security group assigned but one can easily configure it to run within your VPC and subnets with assigning security groups.

Answer (score 2):

**Also Make sure** the lambda attempts to reach a reachable host. in other words make sure that the host **doesn't** reside in a private network, VPN, or an unreachable network (that can't be reached from the externally)

(Trivial but still worth mentioning)

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda and host has to be on the same VPC, also try adding the same security group as of host for lambda