# https "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ..." in AWS

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, https

I couldnt find any solution yet using chatgpt and read related questions in stackoverflow
[checked here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867988/error-getaddrinfo-enotfound-error-when-making-an-https-request)

I just open simple aws lambda that able to make http and https request. (didnt configured nothing, just checked some urls that works)

now , i copy paste a working script with https request from my local envoiremnt and i got

```
"Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND myUrl.co.il",
"    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26)"
```

```
export const handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const params = {
        host: "myUrl.co.il", // myurl is without https! just the DNS
        path: "/login",
        // rejectUnauthorized: false
    };
    const req = https.request(params, function(res) {
        let data = '';
        console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            console.log("DONE");
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        });
    });
    req.end();
};
```